# Some nvidia driver package always asks for upgrade after updated to 450

Tags: 18.04, drivers, apt, nvidia, upgrade

Ubuntu 18.04, After I upgrade to version 450 driver by apt install nvidia-driver-450, the 440 driver packages were automatically remove. Everything works fine but apt always asks me to upgrade those packages:

```
$ apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libnvidia-cfg1-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-common-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 all [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-compute-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-decode-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-encode-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-fbc1-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-gl-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libnvidia-ifr1-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
libxnvctrl0/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
numix-icon-theme-circle/bionic,bionic 19.12.27+202006072001~ubuntu18.04.1 all [upgradable from: 19.12.27+202005141854~ubuntu18.04.1]
nvidia-dkms-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]
nvidia-kernel-source-450/unknown 450.36.06-0ubuntu1 amd64 [upgradable from: 450.36.06-0ubuntu1]


$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-common-450 libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-decode-450
  libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450 libxnvctrl0
  numix-icon-theme-circle nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-kernel-source-450
12 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 96.6 MB/96.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 753 kB of additional disk space will be used.
```

As you can see the version is the same... So after I do this upgrade it still tells me to upgrade.

Of course I did `apt update` and `apt clean` but it still doesn't work.

(NVIDIA drivers from this repo: `deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /` )

Comment: Where did you get `nvidia-driver-450` from? It's not in the standard repos, and that "unknown" looks worrisome.

Comment: From nvidia offical source: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64

Comment: Please edit your question and include full details about where you got the driver and how you installed it. Don't leave out such essential info if you want help, and don't put it in comments.

Comment: I have the same problem. Installed, I believe, via upgrading the cuda and cuda-drivers package from official Nvidia channels (their network-installer .deb file sets up something like a PPA).

Comment: I experience the same problem and noticed this error message in the execution of the update: Checking for existing driver runfile install /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/preinst: 6: [[: not found That error would explain why nothing is actually changed once the upgrade is done. My suspicion is that a shell script containing a `[[ ... ]]` test is being executed using `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` (`sh` doesn't have `[[`). It is likely that there is a bug in nvidia's packaging of `nvidia-common-450`. I reported it on the [nvidia developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/packaging-error-on-l

Comment: This bug seems already fixed.So we have no need to think about this error.

Answer (score 4):

The issue with the metadata in the CUDA repository has been resolved.
Run `apt-get update` and try again.

Also, keep in mind you can file a bug: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia_bug/add

You will need to sign-in/sign-up for a NVIDIA developer account.
Then choose

- Relevant Area

  - Other

    - CUDA Installer

Comment: Works for me. Issue disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that I can ignore this upgrade message without any problem.
So I typed:

```
sudo apt-mark hold libnvidia-cfg1-450 libnvidia-common-450 libnvidia-compute-450 libnvidia-decode-450 libnvidia-encode-450 libnvidia-fbc1-450 libnvidia-gl-450 libnvidia-ifr1-450 libxnvctrl0 nvidia-dkms-450 nvidia-kernel-source-450
```

Now I have no need to type <kbd>n</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you! But I curious about what cause this problem and If it has a update in the future do it still upgradable? Or it needs to unmark?

Answer (score 0):

I have done with uninstall nvidia-settings and reinstall.

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-settings
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

I dont understand why not work with apt-get reinstall nvidia-settings, but with this step work like charm.

Thanks